# Can Windows be setup to use multiple monitors but not have a primary monitor?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

I work as a support developer for an ISV that makes accounting software for Windows.  A customer has reported a strange error.

I tracked the error down to the possibility that the .NET Framework property [Screen.PrimaryScreen](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Screen.cs,6652ece67c0be948) can return null if multi-monitor support is enabled, but there is no primary monitor.  I want to test this scenario with our application.  I have multiple monitors, but I do not see a way to control Windows without a primary monitor enabled.

**Is there a way in Windows to use multiple monitors but not have a primary monitor enabled?**  Changing registry settings would be acceptable.

I have tried unplugging the power and DVI from the primary monitor, disabling it in Windows, and deleting it in Device Manager, but this does not seem to affect anything.

I did find [this discussion](http://discussions.citrix.com/topic/238555-dual-monitor-issue-and-red-x/) that says "primary screen is not defined under special conditions on Citrix Servers":

- Running under seamless mode
- Having a Citrix client using dual screen with primary screen set on the right
- Having a total resolution X color depth of client screens over the maximal video memory allowed on Citrix server

I am not trying to solve this issue from a Citrix perspective.  I was hoping to simulate it in Windows.

Comment: If Windows has a display then it has a primary display.  So the discussion you found would likely be the only condition(s) where that wouldn't be true since in all of them Windows itself wouldn't have a display.  If you tell us more about the error perhaps we can in general terms say how to avoid it, or if provided the troublesome code, help you migrate it to Stackoverflow so it can be fixed.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your response.  My research so far indicates that `Screen.PrimaryScreen` is returning `null`.  Our application tries to reference it without checking for `null` values, so it gets a `NullReferenceException`.  This is going to be easy to avoid.  I was trying to simulate this condition for testing purposes.

Comment: With a debugger attached and after you paused the application, it should be as simple as, changing that value from an actual value to NULL and continue with your execution of the program.  This simulates the condition to the same degree, as if the value was actually NULL, if no primary screen is set it can't be any other value.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I can simulate a `null` value easily in the code.  I cannot figure out how our QA group would test this without duplicating the exact setup.  That is why I asked this question.  Ideally there would be some registry setting we could tweak to simulate this condition.  A "no" answer would be fine-- especially if it included references.